# How to specify "remove_filter('the_content','wpautop');" for certain categories in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I used the following code to apply remove_filter('the_content','wpautop'); to certain categories, but not working

remove_filter('the_content','wpautop');
    add_filter('the_content','my_custom_formatting');

```
function my_custom_formatting($content){

global $post; $post_id =  $post->ID; 
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
            $cats ="";
            $cats = array();

        foreach($post_categories as $c){
               $cat = get_category( $c );
               $cats['cat_id'][] = $cat->cat_ID;
         }

        $catarray=array(353, 181, 7, 176, 4, 12);
        if( count($cats['cat_id']) > 0){
           $intersectcommn_count =  count(array_intersect($catarray, $cats['cat_id']));
           if($intersectcommn_count > 0){


      return wpautop($content);

           }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't an exact answer, but here's a solution for a single category that might lead you on the right path. It removes wpautop from the category named "mycat." I found your post looking for a solution like this, worked it out, and thought I'd share it as I haven't seen it elsewhere (though I'm sure other people must be using it).

Add this to functions.php (or custom.php for Roots).

```
//remove wpautop from "mycat" pages
function remove_autop_for_category( $content )
{
    $category = get_the_category(); 
    'mycat' === $category[0]->cat_name && remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_autop_for_category', 0 );
```